# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate with undefined set as null

Tags: node.js, mongoose, null, undefined, findoneandupdate

I have problem understanding findOneAndUpdate with undefined and null.

when creating an object:

```
const user = new User({
   _id: 1,
   name: "foo",
   address: undefined
});
user.save()
```

It's creating a new document with only name and no address:

```
{
   name: "foo"
}
```

If I'm using the same logic with findOneAndUpdate after:

```
findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1}, {
   name: "bar",
   address: undefined
});
```

the document in the database will now contain a `null` for address:

```
{
   name: "bar",
   address: null,
}
```

Which I can't understand why.

I would expect that when I set a value to `undefined` it should remove the current item,
So if I had for example a document with `address: "somewhere"`, or even without `address` at all, I expect that setting `undefined` should remove it (or not set if wasn't there), instead of set it to null.

Is this something I can achieve somehow? or is this the behavior of findOneAndUpdate? mongodb? (or mongoose?)

Thanks in advance,
Etay.

Comment: If you really want to remove data/field from and document/object i would suggest to use `$unset` operator. For more detail check here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, this is because the method `findOneAndUpdate` have an attribute option that can´t avoid the undefined variables from an object and set a null value by default. To fix this, you only pass the option `"omitUndefined: true"` because by default is false. An example of code to apply:

```
    await this.yourModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
            object._id,
            object,
            {
              new: true,
              omitUndefined: true
            },
          )
```

This solution is only available with Mongoose.

Comment: By the way, as far as I can tell this is a Mongoose feature, so you can't use it if you are using the native MongoDB driver

Comment: That's true szeb, I should remark that is only a solution with Mongoose. It was be an option on the user question but not the single option, thanks.

Comment: With mongoose version 6+ you no longer can or want to use "omitUndefined" option. Mongoose removes `undefined` values instead of coercing them to `null`. More details here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-omitundefined